# Why my useCallback() is rerender evey time?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I read some tutorials on `useCallback()`, including this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNX5iRhczHM I'm sorry, it's in French.

In the tutorials, useCallbacks are only executed once (usually a `console.log()` is present to demonstrate this)

I tried a very simple example, but I don't understand why my `useCallback` (constant `header()`) is rerun every time I press "Increment": I have a console.log each time while I wish it only once :

```
const IndexScreen = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1)

  const header = useCallback(
    () => {
      console.log('execute header')

      return (
        <Text>
          Header
        </Text>
      )
     },
    []
  )

  return (
    <View>
      {header()}
      <Button onPress={() => setCount(count + 1)} title="Increment" />
      <Text>
        {count}
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Thanks you very much

Comment: Because you call it on every render.

Comment: Shouldn't the callback be run within `onPress`?

Comment: What is your motivation for putting it in a useCallback, Gaylord?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useCallback` is used if you want to [memoize a function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) and use it either as dependency or pass it to a child component. This hook makes sure that you get same reference for a function if nothing changed from dependencies.

When your component renders `header()` is a function that will be called every time. And that is expected. What you potentially want is `useMemo` to [prevent triggering](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) of that part of your code every time your component is rerendered:

```js
const IndexScreen = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1)

  const header = useMemo(
    () => {
      console.log('execute header')

      return (
        <Text>
          Header
        </Text>
      )
     },
    []
  )

  return (
    <View>
      {header}
      <Button onPress={() => setCount(count + 1)} title="Increment" />
      <Text>
        {count}
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

`useMemo` should be used rarely since that is an optimization of any hard calculating operation or something that you don't want to be run on every render.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't speak French I cant say much about the tutorial. Sorry :) But I think I can still help you with your example:

Think of `useCallback` as a way to define (more precisely to memoize) a function. In your example this is indeed only done once.

However, the function itself (`() => console.log() ....`) can be executed at any time and as many times as you want by calling it with `header()`.

In you example, since `header()` is part of the return statement it is called every time the component re-renders, e.g. every time it's state changes, e.g. every time `setCounter` changes the counter.